# Angular4 Rendered2 remove label text on addClass method

Tags: angular, validation, bootstrap-4

this is my Component template.

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="form-group">
  <label [attr.for]="field.name" class="{{field.name}}Label form-control-label">{{field.label}}</label>

  <input [formControlName]="field.name" [id]="field.name" class="form-control {{field.name}}Control">
  <small id="{{field.name}}Help" class="form-text"></small>
</div>
```

After a validation process, is necessary add `text-danger` (CSS class) to Label, using `Renderer2 Class` (from Angular4)

```
const label = this.Render.selectRootElement('label[for="' + key + '"]');

this.Render.addClass(label, 'text-danger');
```

`.addClass` method, works fine with input and helper text (below input). But in label tags, this method **DELETE** my `LABEL Text`.

This is a bug? ***@angular 4.3.6***

Form Before Validation

[image: Image Before Validation]

Form After Validation

[image: Image After Validation]

Comment: Make it simpler, just add  [class.text-danger]="form.invalid" on the label tag

Comment: @Vega I don´t use "Angular Validation" for this form, we implement external library. The problem with your answers is evaluate the original object, and depending "node name" set as invalid or valid. But it could be an optional way.

Comment: @Vega this is it https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/  no changes, no customization

Comment: Could you make a minimalistic demo please?

Comment: Here is it :) https://plnkr.co/edit/x2jHrHgODw7oZJgwNlSk?p=preview