# Angular Rendered2 removes first element

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

in other question [Angular4 Rendered2 remove label text on addClass method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288112/angular4-rendered2-remove-label-text-on-addclass-method)

But in this new one, I can not explain why remove the first element.

This is my code for add validation messages:

```
const input = this.Render.selectRootElement('[id="mergePassword"]');
const control = this.Render.selectRootElement('[class="form-group"]');

const errorText = this.Render.createText('error field');
const div = this.Render.createElement('div');
this.Render.appendChild(div, errorText);
this.Render.appendChild(input, div);
this.Render.addClass(input, 'text-danger');
this.Render.addClass(control, 'is-invalid');
```

And this is the demo, when you press button, the input is removed :(

https://plnkr.co/edit/x2jHrHgODw7oZJgwNlSk?p=preview

How can I solve this? (prevent remove the input)

**UPDATE:**

Change logic, instead 2 rootElement, make references from one:

```
const control = this.Render.selectRootElement('[class="form-control"]');
      const errorText = this.Render.createText(error);
      const div = this.Render.createElement('div');
      this.Render.appendChild(div, errorText);
      this.Render.appendChild(this.Render.parentNode(control), div);
      this.Render.addClass(this.Render.parentNode(control), 'text-danger');
      this.Render.addClass(control, 'is-invalid');
```

Comment: why don't you just use a template driven or reactive forms pattern? and render the error message in the html template with *ngIf ? this doesn't seem like a best practice

Comment: @FussinHussin this is an example, ill made with "dynamic" forms, and external validation method. Was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the argument of `createText` to a string, in this line of the UPDATE section,

```
const errorText = this.Render.createText('error');
```

You will get an 'error' text between the input field and the button and the input field will still be present. (confirmed in plunker)

Comment: Are You sure ? I still losing the input field.. on  plunker is like this:     `const errorText = this.Render.createText('error field');`  The "Update", have problem on `removeChild()`, it doesn't remove the child. Renderer2, really is not efficient for DOM manipulation.